# Square of hockey stick identity: $\sum_{i=r}^n{i \choose r}^2$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, contest-math

Evaluate $\sum_{i=r}^n{i \choose r}^2$ where $n,r\in \mathbb{N},n>r$. This looks like the hockey stick identity but I can't find a way to evaluate it without a computer. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I am about 75% certain that this expression has no nice closed form, but I'm gonna think about it for a while more before saying anything too definitive

Comment: I found it...https://oeis.org/A086020
It seems there is a closed form but I cant see any intuitive way how it was determined. What do you think?

Comment: @user2770287 A086020 would be only a particular case ($r=3$), no?

Comment: Yes, I started by looking at a particular case rather than in general.