# Are there any simple simplifications of $\sum_{n=k}^N \binom{n}{k}^2$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

As the title states, is there any simplification to $\sum\limits_{n=k}^N \binom{n}{k}^2$? I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373122/sum-of-square-binomial-coefficients) which sums the squares of the "rows" of a pascal triangle, but here I'm trying to sum the diagonals. There is also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468128/square-of-hockey-stick-identity-sum-i-rni-choose-r2) mathSE question from a few years ago with no answers.

**Update**: I shall clarify that the answer is *not* a central binomial coefficient, nor using the hockey-stick identity. This is directly seen as $\binom{3}{3}^2 + \binom{4}{3}^2 + \binom{5}{3}^3 + \binom{6}{3}^2 = 517$ is not a central binomial coefficient.

Comment: Have you considered writing this as $\sum_{n=k}^N\binom{n}{n-k}^2$ and substituting $n\mapsto n-k$? Then you get $\sum_{n=0}^{N-k}\binom{n+k}k^2$ but that might complicate things...

Comment: Don't use `\limits` in title. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-mathjax-in-question-titles

Comment: @Yooo Ah, I saw someone else add `\limits` so I rejected the edit request to remove it again.

Comment: How do you feel about approximations? I highly suspect there is no closed form for this sum, or even nontrivial simplifications. One way to see this is to recognize this sum as [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function). There's a "well known" algorithm (see, for instance, the book [A=B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html)) which will compute a closed form for such a sum if one exists, and this algorithm is built into [sage](https://sagemath.org). Despite this, sage is unable to simplify this sum.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I don't know what to expect, I am simply trying to generalise the hockey-stick identity. Although I don't know anything about hypergeometric functions, maybe you can write an answer explaining what you said that may help others? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Update: it *might* be [here](https://grossack.site/2021/02/25/sage-sums.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of square binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373122/sum-of-square-binomial-coefficients)

Comment: @Leucippus: No, we have a variable upper limit here. (On the other hand, the vague *any simplification* makes it hard to answer...)

Comment: @metamorphy Yeah I understand the vagueness of the question. I will think more deeply about it and see what I really want to ask :” seeing HallaSurvivor’s comment suggests there’s no closed form (as expected).

Comment: For fixed $k=1,2,3$ etc., this sum has a closed form as a sum of finitely many hypergeometric terms for obvious reasons. The dependence on $k$ is somewhat difficult to quantify. Surely , fixing $N$ large enough perhaps, one can ask if the sum $\sum_{n=k}^{N} \binom{n}{k}^2$ is hypergeometric in $k$. That is what the algorithm must have tried : finding a WZ mate, which likely will not have succeeded. We need to see what kind of dependence on $k$ (specifically) is desired by OP here, because fixing $k$, the dependence on $N$ is actually hypergeometric : not really difficult to prove this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T(n,k)=\sum_{j=k}^{n}{j \choose k}^2$.

Computing some values and then searching OEIS you can find your function at [OEIS A110197](https://oeis.org/A110197). I suppose there isn't a closed form for the general case, because there isn't any there.
However, there are links to special cases sequences and corresponding formulas:

$$T(n,0)=n+1$$
$$T(n,1)=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$$
$$T(n+2,2)=n(n+1)(n+2)(3n^2 + 6n + 1)/60$$

and other cases up to $k=5$.